# Giving properties to datagrid item

Tags: vb.net, properties

This is a bit different.

The following code was taken from a javascript script. What it's (supposedly) doing is assigning properties to the line item. A name, a relations array, rounds array (which they lost in), total wins, three tiebreaker scores, and if they had a bye. (This is for a swiss pairing algorithm.)

```
    data[pid] = {
        name: name,
        relations: {},
        rounds: {},
        wins: 0,
        tie1: 0,
        tie2: 0,
        tie3: 0,
        hadBye: false
    };
```

I want to do something like this in Visual Basic. I'm pulling data from a table using a `OleDBReader`. I want to give each item that is pulled a set of these properties. Then by some means changing them.

How do I get started with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.  I've setup a pretty simple example.

First I created a `LineItem` object class that looks something like this:

```
Public Class LineItem

    Public Property name As String
    Public Property relations As List(Of String)
    Public Property rounds As List(Of String)
    Public Property wins As Integer
    Public Property tie1 As Integer
    Public Property tie2 As Integer
    Public Property tie3 As Integer
    Public Property hadBye As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String)
        'Just a simple constructor
        Me.name = name
    End Sub

    'No methods for the sake of simplicity

End Class
```

Then in the method that is performing all of the work, I create a new `LineItem` and simply setup some properties for it like so:

```
Private Sub SetupMyObject()
        Dim lineItem1 As New LineItem("myName")
        'Add some relations
        lineItem1.relations.Add("firstRelation")
        lineItem1.relations.Add("secondRelation")
        'Add some rounds
        lineItem1.rounds.Add("firstRound")
        lineItem1.rounds.Add("secondRound")
        'Set wins
        lineItem1.wins = 4
        'Set tie1
        lineItem1.tie1 = 2
        'set tie2
        lineItem1.tie2 = 0
        'set tie3
        lineItem1.tie3 = 3
        'Set the bye flag
        lineItem1.hadBye = False
    End Sub
```

This code is pretty abstract so modifying it to conform to your needs shouldn't be too difficult.